# Does this Code have any obvious Errors, like "open loop" or "not finished?

Tags: c#, url

**First of all:** I can't "speak" C# but i know a bit how a programming language works.

**About**
I am trying to implement a C# Skript in a Genetec Video Surveillance System Makro. It should send a HTTPS-GET-Request to change a Parameter on the Server.

**Build**
I am in a separated VLAN with no Internet-Connection. I guess it has a Proxy who allows this URL to get through. The URL works perfectly fine in the Browser.

**Problem**
It manifests as following: I can start the script and it works. When i start it again later it does nothing. (Maybe it works anytime later, but i could not confirm this)

The Code is made of what the last person has left behind after leaving and some ChatGPT help. ChatGPT added the random Parameter. *I implemented this because the person who build the counterpart (URL-Side) said it could be a Problem with a Proxy Cache.*

**Questions**
Is there a Problem in the Code?
Do i need to add something to make it run better/more secure?

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Genetec.Sdk;
using Genetec.Sdk.Entities;
using Genetec.Sdk.Enumerations;
using Genetec.Sdk.Queries;
using Genetec.Sdk.Scripting;
using Genetec.Sdk.Scripting.Interfaces.Attributes;
using System;

[MacroParameters()]
public sealed class myMacro : UserMacro
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point of the macro. Provide an implementation of this method.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Execute()
    {
        // Generiere einen zufälligen Wert für rand
        string randomValue = GenerateRandomValue();

        // Ersetze den festen Wert von rand in der URL mit dem zufälligen Wert
        string url = "https://ANYURL.com/cgi-bin/control2.php?key2=ENTER_KEY&cam5=0&rand=" + randomValue;

        WebRequest wrGETURL;
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.IO.Stream objStream;
        objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generiert einen zufälligen alphanumerischen String.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Zufälliger String.</returns>
    private string GenerateRandomValue()
    {
        const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        Random random = new Random();
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 10).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the macro needs to clean up. 
    /// </summary>
    protected override void CleanUp()
    {
        // Release objects created by the Execute method, unhook events, and so on.
    }
}
```

Note: ANYURL and  ENTER_KEY is in the finished code inserted. i can not publish these, sorry.

**What i tried**
I added the random part to the URL to be shure it is no problem with the proxy cache. I asked chatgpt what could be wrong. I checked most of it *(i could not yet absolutely verify the firewall allowing every request but when it works in the Browser it should also work directly from Security Center/Genetec)*

**Solution i(ChatGPT) found:**

```
using System;
//using System.IO;
using System.Net;
//using Genetec.Sdk;
//using Genetec.Sdk.Entities;
//using Genetec.Sdk.Enumerations;
//using Genetec.Sdk.Queries;
using Genetec.Sdk.Scripting;
using Genetec.Sdk.Scripting.Interfaces.Attributes;

[MacroParameters()]
public sealed class myMacro : UserMacro
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point of the macro. Provide an implementation of this method.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "https://ANYURL.com/cgi-bin/control2.php?key2=ENTER_KEY&cam5=1";
            WebRequest wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(url);

            using (WebResponse response = wrGETURL.GetResponse())
            using (System.IO.Stream objStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Process the response stream here
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log or handle the exception appropriately
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the macro needs to clean up. 
    /// </summary>
    protected override void CleanUp()
    {
        // Release objects created by the Execute method, unhook events, and so on.
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Revert any changes introduced by ChatGPT. It looks as if Jibbidy tried to trick the caching by providing an unknown key everytime. That doesn't seem to work, though as by your observations.

Comment: 2. Instead, I _think_ this is what you need : [WebRequest.CachePolicy Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.cachepolicy?view=net-8.0)

Comment: ^^ Mind that ChatGPT _does not know how to code_. It just parrots snippets of what it has its hands on. The results are not safe to use. They may not work, not _actually_ make sense or even introduce vulnerabilities if you don't know what you are doing _exactly_ and capable of judging the result.

Comment: _"the person who build the counterpart (URL-Side) said it could be a Problem with a Proxy Cache"_ - If you have that person at hand, it is no disgrace to ask them if they happen to know how to fix it. The worst they can say is "no". I don't know what genetec is writing in, I know a competitor (if they still exist, it's been a few days) uses Java. But any dev should have been able to push you into the direction of some sort of cache policy in the request.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers. I will ask the Counterpart person if she may can help.

Comment: And investigate in the rootcase

U may know if a C# Skript need a "End" or similar? or does the skript just run and afterwards "close itself"?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "script" in C# unless you are writing explixitly C#-Script (.csx). Are you?

Comment: It looks more like a plugin that is being created and called from a framework (i.e. the genetec application), so I expect lifetime to be for the runtime of the `Execute` method _unless there is documentation for it being different from that for the API_.

Comment: I (or Chatgpt) solved it. I don't know why it works now but these are different than before: 

The middle part gets "called" with ```try``` and ```catch (Excepition ex)```
This is also different:
```using (WebResponse response = wrGETURL.GetResponse())```
```using (System.IO.Stream objStream = response.GetResponseStream())```

If someone needs the whole script, hit me up

Comment: It's encouraged to answer your own question in cases like this. @Andurill

Comment: I hope i did it right with editing the original post. Else please tell me